# Modify specific parameter value in the URL without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, url

I have a URL

`http://localhost/revamp/search.php?city=chennai&V&locality=mylapore&sort_val=sort_price`

In this URL, I just need to update the `sort_val=sort_distance` in the URL on selecting the distance option without reloading the page.

```
<select name="sort_val" class="sort_select">
 <option value="sort_distance">Sort by Distance</option>
 <option value="sort_price">Sort by Price</option>
 <option value="sort_ratings">Sort by Ratings</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried googling at all? 1 - fire Javascript event on option select; 2 - change url param with javascript;  Then put those 2 together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use below solution, I hope it will helps to you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var queries = {};
    $.each(document.location.search.substr(1).split('&'), function(c,q){
        var i = q.split('=');
        queries[i[0].toString()] = unescape(i[1].toString()); // change escaped characters in actual format
    });
    $(".sort_select").change(function(){
       queries[$(this).attr('name')]=$(this).val();
     history.pushState({}, '', "?"+$.param(queries));
    });
})
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It is working. But, the `+` in the URL is replaced by `%2B` code and while decoding, it is taking `%2B` to `+` which needs to be a `space` between those words

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala, please refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ for more detail, if still you stuck.. please message me.. i am here. :) and dont forget to mark as right and up vote ;)

Comment: thanks @VyshnaviSamudrala, please try with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qqbztc6z/ let me know if you need help from me ;)

Comment: However, it worked and I'm replacing the + with a space in my PHP file.. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I have shared something for you in js fiddle will be help to you in future.. Anyways, for + signture will convert %2B, but you can use php side urlencode() and urldecode() functions.

Comment: It is encoding again and again.. First, it is replacing `%` in `%20B` to `%2520B` and again on executing, `%252520B` and then to `%25252520B` and so on!!!

Comment: Glade to here from you, please read commented code  js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qqbztc6z/2/ and give some time

Comment: Hi @VyshnaviSamudrala have you checked that fiddle and followed?